# OWLAPI: The method addAxioms is deprecated

Tags: owl, owl-api

In the new OWLAPI the method addAxioms seems to be deprecated, because the compiler shows me this warning.
What is the new way to do that? Is that dangerous keep using this method?

Comment: It's not dangerous - deprecated methods won't be removed before version 6. It's a nudge towards the new interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Javadocs:

> @deprecated use {@link #addAxioms(OWLOntology, Stream)} instead.